# How to convert .txt file contents into .html format using perl?

Tags: html, perl, html-table

I tried to convert .txt into .html format.So i tried the following code to convert and also need to give different heading names for every column in table format  using perl.

Input file:`input.txt`

```
1:Explicit Placement blockages are created in the pad regions ?:Yes:INCORRECT:To Be Done
2:Explicit Routing blockages are created in the pad regions ?:Yes:INCORRECT:To Be Done
3:Is Complete bond pad meal is used for top level power hookup ?:Yes:INCORRECT:To Be Done
```

**code which i tried:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open my $HTML, '>', 'output.html' or die $!;
print $HTML <<'_END_HEADER_';
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
_END_HEADER_
open my $IN, '<', 'input.txt' or die $!;
while (my $line = <$IN>) {
    $convert=split(/\:/,$line);
    print $HTML $convert;
}
print $HTML '</body></html>';
close $HTML or die $!;
```

Expected output:

Column 1 should print the entire sentence for every  line according to serial number vice. i.e from (Explicit Placement blockages are created in the pad regions)

```
|s.no|column1      |column2|column3  |column4    |
|1   |Explicit.... |yes    |INCORRECT|To be done |
|2   |Explicit.... |yes    |INCORRECT|To be done |
|1   |Is.......... |yes    |INCORRECT|To be done |
```

Comment: What is your expected output, and your received output? Because you mention "heading names for every column", but there is nothing in your code for columns. If it's giving you an actual error or warning, what is the message?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/) page for more about what folks are looking for.  In this case, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42400948/edit) to include the output you expect, and the output you are actually seeing.

Comment: Also, `split` returns an array. The way you're using it, into a scalar, I believe returns the size of the resulting array, not the elements of the split.

Comment: i tried split to remove colon and it should form table format.@AntonH

Comment: @AntonH Nit-picky, but `split` doesn't return an array, it returns a list in list context and the size of the list in scalar context.

Comment: @shuttlefolks From what I see: 1) you want to use the elements of the split. You need to capture the result into an array: `@convert = ...`. Use it that way. 2) there is no code there to make it a table. No `<table>` tags or `<td>` or anything. Do that.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot True, but given the code, I was (possibly erroneously) trying to simply for OP.

Comment: Okay@ThisSuitIsBlackNot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With minimal changes to your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $HTML, '>', 'output.html' or die $!;
print $HTML <<'_END_HEADER_';
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<table>
_END_HEADER_

open my $IN, '<', 'input.txt' or die $!;
while (my $line = <$IN>) {
    chomp $line;
    print $HTML '<tr><td>' . join('</td><td>', split(/:/,$line)) . "</td></tr>\n";
    #or
    #print $HTML '<tr><td>' . $line =~ s|:|</td><td>|gr . "</td></tr>\n";
}
close $IN or die $!;
print $HTML <<'_END_FOOTER_';
</table>
</body>
</html>
_END_FOOTER_
close $HTML or die $!;
```

will produce the following html-table:

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Explicit Placement blockages are created in the pad regions ?</td><td>Yes</td><td>INCORRECT</td><td>To Be Done</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Explicit Routing blockages are created in the pad regions ?</td><td>Yes</td><td>INCORRECT</td><td>To Be Done</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>Is Complete bond pad meal is used for top level power hookup ?</td><td>Yes</td><td>INCORRECT</td><td>To Be Done</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```