# How to bold the row in the html page using perl?

Tags: perl

I tried to highlight rows without serial number to bold.I used the following code to convert the row to bold using perl.

#### My code:

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $HTML, '>', 'result.html' or die $!;

print $HTML <<'_END_HEADER_';
<html>
<head><title>welcome</title></head>
<body>
<table border=10>
<th>SL.NO</th><th>CHECKLIST ITEM</th><th>VALUE</th><th>COMMENTS</th><th>CONFIRMATION</th>
_END_HEADER_

open my $IN, '<', 'result.txt' or die $!;

while ( my $line = <$IN> ) {
    chomp $line;
    #$line=~ s/COMMENT//g;
    $line =~ s/[\\\_\@\_]//g;
    $line =~ s/COMMENT//g;
    # print $line;
    print $HTML '<tr><td>' . join( '</td><td>', split( /:/, $line ) ) . "</td></tr>\n";
}

close $IN or die $!;

print $HTML <<'_END_FOOTER_';
</table>
</body>
</html>
_END_FOOTER_

close $HTML or die $!;
```

#### result.txt

```
CREATED_BY=ME
1:Is Synopsys RM flow used?:Yes:INCORRECT:To Be Done
COMMENT:Full Planned_\@_
2:Any Blockages Used?:Yes:INCORRECT:To Be Done
COMMENT:CTS_\@_
```

#### Output Generated:(i.e result.html)

```
SL.NO   CHECKLIST_ITEM  VALUE   COMMENTS    CONFIRMATION
CREATEDBY=ME                
1   Is flow is used?    YES     INCORRECT   To Be Done
    Full Planned            
2   Any Blockages Used? Yes INCORRECT   To Be Done
    CTS
```

#### Expected output:

```
CREATEDBY=ME

SL.NO   CHECKLIST_ITEM  VALUE   COMMENTS    CONFIRMATION
1   Is flow is used?    YES     INCORRECT   To Be Done
    Full Planned            
2   Any Blockages Used? Yes INCORRECT   To Be Done
    CTS
```

Here I like to highlight the unserial number rows(i.e Full planned and CTS) to be highlighted.

Comment: Your code does not compile because you have `strict` but the first two variables are never declared. You're talking about `result.txt` but your code only writes to a `result.html`. You also have lots of HTML that you write to that file, but the output and expected output you show us is plain-text. If you want to make something bold in HTML, put it into a `<b></b>` tag.

Comment: Here i tried to copy that ouput in table format but it copied as text@simbabque

Comment: I tried the above code so that the output is generated.i did copy of the generated output here@simbabque

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I am guessing reading the links in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400948/how-to-convert-txt-file-contents-into-html-format-using-perl#comment71949061_42400948) will help, if you haven't already :) .  Also, the [formatting help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) may help with the issue you had trying to paste your results in.  If you indent each line of your pasted HTML with four spaces, it should come through as source rather than as rendered output.

Comment: @cxw: There is no HTML markup in the question's source!

Comment: @Borodin agreed.  I am guessing based on [the OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42420855/how-to-bold-the-row-in-the-html-page-using-perl?noredirect=1#comment71988491_42420855) that the OP tried to paste HTML and had formatting problems.  It's just a guess, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to embolden text in HTML is to use [Cascading Style Sheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets). You should change your code to insert a class in the `<tr>` elements that need to be bold. Instead of this:

```
print $HTML '<tr><td>' . join('</td><td>', split(/:/,$line)) . "</td></tr>\n";
```

I would suggest something like this:

```
my @data = split /:/, $line;
my $class = $data[0] ? 'bold' : 'normal';
print $HTML qq[<tr class="$class"><td>] . join('</td><td>', @data) . "</td></tr>\n";
```

And then a CSS file that contains a rule like this:

```
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: `split /:/, $line` is already in `@data`; there is no need to recalculate it in the `print` statement. I would also prefer to see `print "<td>$_</td>\n" for @data` instead of the `join`.

Comment: @Borodin: Thanks. I really shouldn't rush these answers just before leaving work :-) I've fixed the `split`/`@data` error. But I've left your other suggestion, as I was trying to make as small a change as possible. Obviously, I'd really do this with a template.

Comment: That's fine. One of the core principles of Stack Overflow is that we are here to fix one-another's oversights. And my second point was purely personal preference; your answer is fine as it is.